# Retrieving checkbox values from DE in cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

Maybe it's basic, but I simply can't figure this out. 
I have a cloudpage which I would like to use as a preference center, and therefore I need to retrieve the values of checkboxes. True/False = checked/unchecked.

I have defined all fields in the top of the page with AMPscript, 
example:

```
%%[
  SET @Id = QueryParameter('id')
  SET @Rows = LookupRows('Kontakter','Customer ID',@Id)
  IF ROWCOUNT(@Rows) > 0 THEN
SET @vvs = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),'interesser_vvs_inst__c')
 ENDIF
  ]%%
```

And in my smart-capture this is what I have inserted:

```
<div class="smartcapture-controls"><div class="sc-formfield-label"></div>
<div class="sc-formfield-input-wrapper">

  <div class="sc-formfield-input">
%%[IF @vvs == True THEN]%%
      <input name="vvs" value="Y" type="checkbox" checked=""> 
%%[Else]%%
      <input name="vvs" value="Y" type="checkbox"> 
%%[ENDIF]%%
  </div></div></div>
```

Is there someone who can point me in the right direction, or is this the way to do it ?

Best Regards, 
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the `@vvs` variable will have the values of TRUE/FALSE, you could do the following:

```
%%[
  SET @Id = QueryParameter('id')
  SET @Rows = LookupRows('Kontakter','Customer ID',@Id)
  IF ROWCOUNT(@Rows) > 0 THEN
  SET @vvs = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),'interesser_vvs_inst__c')
    IF @vvs == TRUE THEN
    SET @checked = "checked"
    ELSE    
    SET @checked = ""
    ENDIF
  ENDIF
 ]%%


<div class="smartcapture-controls"><div class="sc-formfield-label"></div>
<div class="sc-formfield-input-wrapper">

<div class="sc-formfield-input">
<input name="vvs" value="Y" type="checkbox" %%=v(@checked)=%%> 

</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Nice clean solution Zuzannamj

Comment: @zuzannamj, thanks for the answer! It seems that my cloudpage dont want to publish, so I must have done something wrong. However I see your point, and understand what your code does! Thank you:)

Comment: Glad I could help! Please remember to accept the answer :)

Comment: Hmm... It sets false values to checked as well?

Comment: No, for false it will remain blank, so in the place where “checked” would be, there will be a blank value, which means it will not be checked.

Comment: Figured it out! perfect:)

Comment: Congratulations :)